# Deleting an Image inside a Wiki Page or delete the whole Wiki page , will not remove its related Images from the “Images” library

Tags: development, publishing-site, publishing-page, enterprise-wiki

I have noted the following strange behavior inside my Publishing enterprise wiki site collection.
Now by default when I create a new wiki page and I add Pictures to it, the pictures will be saved under the “Images” library and will be inside a unique folder that have its name similar to the page name.
But when users delete the picture from the wiki page or they delete the whole wiki page, then the related folder inside the “Images” library will not be removed. So can anyone advice if there is a way to automatically remove the page’s pictures folder from the Images library when the page is deleted?